# Should i modify the prototype of String?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was about to create a trim function in javascript, but as i don't want to reinvent the wheel i googled for this method.
I found this link 
http://www.somacon.com/p355.php

The Solution it provided is:

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
String.prototype.ltrim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+/,"");
}
String.prototype.rtrim = function() {
    return this.replace(/\s+$/,"");
}
```

also it says if you don'y wnt to change the prototype of String then use this:

```
function trim(stringToTrim) {
    return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
function ltrim(stringToTrim) {
    return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+/,"");
}
function rtrim(stringToTrim) {
    return stringToTrim.replace(/\s+$/,"");
}
```

I would like to know in  what scenario one should **not** modify the prototype of String or say any object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `trim` functions are to be standardised in ECMAScript Fifth Edition, as well as already being present in some browsers. So:

1. Yes, adding them to the prototype is totally appropriate, but
2. You shouldn't add them to the prototype if they're already there, as you'll just be replacing a fast native-code function with a slow JavaScript one.

It is also typically marginally faster to do trim as two replaces:

```
// Add ECMA262-5 string trim if not supported natively
//
if (!('trim' in String.prototype)) {
    String.prototype.trim= function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
    };
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with if (!String.prototype.trim)? Looks more efficient to me.

Comment: `in` is more explicit about what it's testing for, not relying on the truthiness of a property or the bizarre and terrible JavaScript quirk of retuning a new `undefined` for something that any other language would consider an exception. For this particular case of course it doesn't matter at all, but in general I always use `in` for testing if an object has a property.

Answer (score 3):

In general - do not modify a prototype of buildin objects.
But ofcourse you can add your handy function.

And always check before you add:

```
//pre-1.6 javascript
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt) {
        var len = this.length >>> 0;
        var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
        from = (from < 0) ? Math.ceil(from) : Math.floor(from);
        if (from < 0)
            from += len;
        for (; from < len; from++) {
            if (from in this && this[from] === elt)
                return from;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}
```

This way you didn't overwrite mush faster buildin function that may become available sometime...

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of very useful utility function, I'd say you can modify the prototype.
But you should be aware that the function may already exist natively in a few browsers, so you should check it : https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String

Comment: and in which case you should not, is it related to somekind of overhead or what?

Comment: there is no "you shouldn't" case, just be aware of what Fabien said.

Comment: great javascript 1.8.1 is having string.trim() method  https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: only if i could accept 2 answers, i would have accepted yours too